# setgraphicsAPIs is Overloaded Method match (C# Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Can someone help me

```
PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs (BuildTarget.Android, TargetGlesGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0);
```

gives me this compile error :

> Assets/_Developer/JEONG/Editor/BuildEditor.cs(776,18): error CS1502:
>   The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs(UnityEditor.Buil‌​dTarget,
>   UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType[])' has some invalid
>   arguments

I don't know why but i follow the documentation in Unity

Comment: You don't know why what ? Can you please copy the full error message into your question ?

Comment: @Pac0 Assets/_Developer/JEONG/Editor/BuildEditor.cs(776,18): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs(UnityEditor.BuildTarget, UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: The error tells you clearly that the second parameter needs to be an array, not a single value, so you should change `TargetGlesGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0` to `new[]{TargetGlesGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0}`

Comment: @UnholySheep so its something like this `PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs (BuildTarget.Android, new[]{TargetGlesGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0});` it doesnt work

Comment: Right, you are actually using the wrong enum type here as well - it needs to be `GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES2` instead of `TargetGlesGraphics.OpenGLES_2_0` (and in the array form as per my previous comment)

Comment: @UnholySheep still got this error sir `The best overloaded method match for `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs(UnityEditor.BuildTarget, UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType[])' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you sir Pac but i tried this one

```
PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs (BuildTarget.Android, new [] {UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES2});
```

and it works . Thank you also to everyone that help me. Sorry for my bad english

Comment: For your information, you used the version with the *full namespace*. If you want to use the "short version" without having to write the namespace (like in my example), you can just add `using UnityEngine.Rendering;` on the top of the file, before class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You should call it like that :

```
PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs (BuildTarget.Android, new [] { GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES3 });
```

As per the error message, the function is expecting an **array** of GraphicsDeviceType. Since you want only one  device type, you still have to provide an array where there is one element.

Also, the value is `GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES3` (full name with namespace : `UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType.OpenGLES3` ), and not  `TargetGlesGraphics.Whatever` .

You can see in error message that it expects a value as an array of `GraphicsDeviceType`, so I searched the unity doc to find this :

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType.html

Comment: It still the same and the second error is this >Assets/_Developer/JEONG/Editor/BuildEditor.cs(776,56): error CS1503: Argument `#2' cannot convert `UnityEditor.TargetGlesGraphics[]' expression to type `UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType[]'

Comment: @NoobProgrammer : I edited my answer, please have a look at it

Comment: error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEditor.PlayerSettings.SetGraphicsAPIs(UnityEditor.BuildTarget, UnityEngine.Rendering.GraphicsDeviceType[])' has some invalid arguments this is the error now

Comment: so apparently OPENGLES3 is for some reason not valid for you.